# Custom EditorTemplate not returning Form values Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model that has a complex type as a property. I have created a custom DisplayEditor for the complex child type, and it is being bound correctly when the page is loaded. When the page is posted after edits have been made, the Dependents type is being set to null. Here is the code for the Employee model that represents the child Dependents property:

```
[Display(Name = "Dependents")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public List<Dependent> Dependents { get; set; }
```

Here is the Dependent model:

```
[Serializable]
public class Dependent : Person
{
    public Dependent()
    {
        Deduction deduction = new Deduction(this) { Amount = Constants.DependentDeductionAmount };
        this.Deduction = deduction;
    }

    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int DependentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Dependent Type")]
    public DependentType DependentType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public override double DeductionAmount => Constants.DependentDeductionAmount;
}
```

The 2 edit action methods on the employee controller (I've tried TryUpdateModel, doesn't work):

```
    public ViewResult Edit(int employeeId)
    {
        if (employeeId < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(employeeId));

        Employee employee = _employeeRepository.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId);

        bool result = TryUpdateModel(employee, new FormValueProvider(ControllerContext));

        return View(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
    {
        if (employee == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(employee));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            employee.Changed = true;
            employee.Dependents.ForEach(d => d.Changed = true);
            _employeeRepository.SaveEmployee(employee);
            TempData["message"] = $"{employee} has been saved.";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else {
            // there is something wrong with the data values
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Edit.cshtml:

```
@model Paylocity.HR.Domain.Entities.Employee

@{
    ViewBag.Title = $"{"Edit"} {Model}";
}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3>@ViewBag.Title</h3>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employee"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr/>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dependents, "Dependents")   
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId)
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel and return to List", "Index", null, new {@class = "btn btn-default"})
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Here is the Dependent.cshtml EditorTemplate:

```
@model IEnumerable<Dependent>
@using Paylocity.HR.Domain.Entities

@foreach (var dep in Model)
{
<h4>Dependent</h4>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => dep.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => dep.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => dep.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => dep.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => dep.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => dep.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => dep.DependentType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => dep.DependentType, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => dep.DependentType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
}
```

The employee object binds correctly and is updateable, it's only the dependents child type that isn't being bound correctly. The HTML is displaying the correct ID's/names for the Dependent form fields (I believe?). Do I need to implement some sort of custom binder code, or am I missing something obvious here?

This is my first question on SO, I hope I provided enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the model in the  `Dependent.cshtml` template to `@model Dependent` (it cant be `IEnumerable<T>`) and remove the `foreach` loop which is generating `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model (and duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html)

It also needs be located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` or `/Views/yourControllerName/EditorTemplates/` folder

```
@model Dependent
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
...
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

etc. Then in the main view, use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dependents)
```

The `EditorFor()` method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and will generate the correct html for each item in the collection including the correct `name` attributes with indexers

Comment: I thought I had tried this approach already (changing the EditorTemplate to not use a collection, and bind directly to the collection in the main view), but apparently I hadn't, or missed something in that process. This is the answer, I knew it'd be something simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the way you generating the list of item.

use index instead of foreach.

hence your Dependent.cshtml EditorTemplate

do something like:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
<h4>Dependent</h4>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model[i].FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

// rest field follow same pattern
}
```

for more info about binding list, checkout this post
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: This would have worked as well. Upvoting, but marking Stephen's as answer b/c it's cleaner. Thanks though!

Comment: Actually this would not have worked. The model must be `IList<T>` in order to use a `for` loop.